# Aligning my input fields

Tags: html, css

I would like to have my input fields on the left align horizontally without affecting the margin. I set the margin to 0 so that the form will remain in the center of the page of all times. And could you also make the subject and text area align with each other also. because it is not in sync at all

```css
body {
  font-size: 100%;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2.3em;
  /*1em = 16px.*/
}


/*OVERALL FORM EDITING*/

form {
  margin: auto;
  /*used to center the form*/
  width: 700px;
  /*prevents the form from stretching over the whole page*/
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding: 20px;
  /*pads the inside of the form*/
  font-size: 0.875em;
  /*1em = 16px.*/
}


/*OVERALL FORM EDITING*/

.center-element {
  text-align: center;
}

.float-right {
  float: right;
}


/*position input fields to the right on the form*/


/*INPUT FIELDS*/

input[type="text"] {
  /*controls the size, color, e.t.c for the input "text" fields */
  border-radius: 7px;
  border: 2px solid #f4511e;
  padding: 6px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 190px;
}

input[type="text"]:focus {
  /*for the color inside the input "text" fields when clicked*/
  background-color: #9BDFE4;
}

input[type="number"] {
  /*controls the size, color, e.t.c for the input "number" fields */
  display: inline-block;
  /*allows our elements to have a width and a height.*/
  border-radius: 7px;
  border: 2px solid #F28C6D;
  padding: 6px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
  width: 190px;
  /*used to specify the size of the input fields*/
}

input[type="number"]:focus {
  /*for the color inside the input "number" fields when clicked*/
  background-color: #9BDFE4;
}


/*INPUT FIELDS*/


/*BUTTONS*/

#submit-form-button {
  /*for the "Get Started" button*/
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 12px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #F28C6D;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}

#submit-form-button:hover {
  /*controls the color of the "Get Started" button when you hover over it*/
  background-color: #EB4408;
}

#reset-button {
  /*for the "Clear form" button*/
  border-radius: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #9BDFE4;
  float: right;
  outline: none;
}

#reset-button:hover {
  /*controls the color of the "Clear form" button when you hover over it*/
  background-color: #0066CC;
}


/*BUTTONS*/


/*DROPDOWN MENUS*/

#dropForm {
  display: inline-block;
  /*allows our elements to have a width and a height.*/
  border-radius: 7px;
  border: 2px solid #f4511e;
  padding: 6px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
  width: 190px;
  /*used to specify the size of the input fields*/
}


/*DROPDOWN MENUS*/


/*TEXT AREA BOX & SUBJECT AREA BOX*/

#sub {
  width: 390px;
  padding: 12px;
}

#notePad {
  border-radius: 7px;
  border: 2px solid #f4511e;
  padding: 12px;
  outline: none;
  resize: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#notePad:focus {
  background-color: #9BDFE4;
}


/*TEXT AREA BOX & SUBJECT BOX AREA*/
```

```html
<form>


  <div id="aligning-input-fields">
    <label for="firstname">First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" required/>

    <div class="float-right">
      <label for="lastname">Last Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="lastname" required/>
    </div>

    <br />
    <br />

    <label for="email-1">Enter your e-mail:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email-1" required/>

    <div class="float-right">
      <label for="email-2">Confirm your email:</label>
      <input type="text" name="email-2" required/>
    </div>

    <br />
    <br />

    <label for="drop1">Country:</label>
    <select name="drop1" id="dropForm">
                            <option value="au">Australia</option>
                            <option value="al">Albania</option>
                            <option value="dz">Algeria</option>
                            <option value="ao">Angola</option>
                            <option value="ai">Anguilla</option>
                            <option value="ag">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
                            <option value="ar">Argentina</option>
                            <option value="am">Armenia</option>
                            <option value="aw">Aruba</option>
                            <option value="at">Austria</option>
                            <option value="az">Azerbaijan</option>
                            <option value="bs">Bahamas</option>
                            <option value="bh">Bahrain</option>
                            <option value="bd">Bangladesh</option>
                            <option value="bb">Barbados</option>
                            <option value="by">Belarus</option>
                            <option value="be">Belgium</option>
                            <option value="bz">Belize</option>
                            <option value="bj">Benin</option>
                            <option value="bm">Bermuda</option>
                            <option value="bt">Bhutan</option>
                            <option value="bo">Bolivia</option>
                            <option value="ba">Bosnia and Herzegovina</option>
                            <option value="bw">Botswana</option>
                            <option value="br">Brazil</option>
                            <option value="vg">British Virgin Islands</option>
                            <option value="bn">Brunei</option>
                            <option value="bg">Bulgaria</option>
                            <option value="bf">Burkina Faso</option>
                            <option value="ca">Canada</option>
                            <option value="kh">Cambodia</option>
                            <option value="cm">Cameroon</option>
                            <option value="cv">Cape Verde</option>
                            <option value="ky">Cayman Islands</option>
                            <option value="td">Chad</option>
                            <option value="cl">Chile</option>
                            <option value="cn">China</option>
                            <option value="co">Colombia</option>
                            <option value="cr">Costa Rica</option>
                            <option value="hr">Croatia</option>
                            <option value="cy">Cyprus</option>
                            <option value="cz">Czech Republic</option>
                            <option value="ci">Côte d&#39;Ivoire</option>
                            <option value="dk">Denmark</option>
                            <option value="dm">Dominica</option>
                            <option value="do">Dominican Republic</option>
                            <option value="ec">Ecuador</option>
                            <option value="eg">Egypt</option>
                            <option value="sv">El Salvador</option>
                            <option value="ee">Estonia</option>
                            <option value="fj">Fiji</option>
                            <option value="fi">Finland</option>
                            <option value="fr">France</option>
                            <option value="ga">Gabon</option>
                            <option value="gm">Gambia</option>
                            <option value="de">Germany</option>
                            <option value="gh">Ghana</option>
                            <option value="gr">Greece</option>
                            <option value="gd">Grenada</option>
                            <option value="gu">Guam (USA)</option>
                            <option value="gt">Guatemala</option>
                            <option value="gw">Guinea-Bissau</option>
                            <option value="gy">Guyana</option>
                            <option value="ht">Haiti</option>
                            <option value="hn">Honduras</option>
                            <option value="hk">Hong Kong</option>
                            <option value="hu">Hungary</option>
                            <option value="is">Iceland</option>
                            <option value="in">India</option>
                            <option value="id">Indonesia</option>
                            <option value="ie">Ireland</option>
                            <option value="il">Israel</option>
                            <option value="it">Italy</option>
                            <option value="jm">Jamaica</option>
                            <option value="jp">日本</option>
                            <option value="jo">Jordan</option>
                            <option value="kz">Kazakhstan</option>
                            <option value="ke">Kenya</option>
                            <option value="kw">Kuwait</option>
                            <option value="kg">Kyrgyzstan</option>
                            <option value="la">Laos</option>
                            <option value="lv">Latvia</option>
                            <option value="lb">Lebanon</option>
                            <option value="lr">Liberia</option>
                            <option value="li">Liechtenstein</option>
                            <option value="lt">Lithuania</option>
                            <option value="lu">Luxembourg</option>
                            <option value="mo">Macau</option>
                            <option value="mk">Macedonia</option>
                            <option value="mg">Madagascar</option>
                            <option value="mw">Malawi</option>
                            <option value="my">Malaysia</option>
                            <option value="ml">Mali</option>
                            <option value="mt">Malta</option>
                            <option value="mr">Mauritania</option>
                            <option value="mu">Mauritius</option>
                            <option value="mx">Mexico</option>
                            <option value="fm">Micronesia</option>
                            <option value="md">Moldova (Republic of)</option>
                            <option value="mn">Mongolia</option>
                            <option value="ms">Montserrat</option>
                            <option value="ma">Morocco</option>
                            <option value="mz">Mozambique</option>
                            <option value="mm">Myanmar</option>
                            <option value="na">Namibia</option>
                            <option value="np">Nepal</option>
                            <option value="nl">Netherlands</option>
                            <option value="nz">New Zealand</option>
                            <option value="ni">Nicaragua</option>
                            <option value="ne">Niger</option>
                            <option value="ng">Nigeria</option>
                            <option value="mp">Northern Mariana Islands (USA)</option>
                            <option value="no">Norway</option>
                            <option value="om">Oman</option>
                            <option value="pk">Pakistan</option>
                            <option value="pw">Palau</option>
                            <option value="pa">Panama</option>
                            <option value="pg">Papua New Guinea</option>
                            <option value="py">Paraguay</option>
                            <option value="pe">Peru</option>
                            <option value="ph">Philippines</option>
                            <option value="pl">Poland</option>
                            <option value="pt">Portugal</option>
                            <option value="pr">Puerto Rico (USA)</option>
                            <option value="qa">Qatar</option>
                            <option value="cg">Republic Of Congo</option>
                            <option value="ro">Romania</option>
                            <option value="ru">Russia</option>
                            <option value="rw">Rwanda</option>
                            <option value="kn">Saint Kitts &amp; Nevis Anguilla</option>
                            <option value="lc">Saint Lucia</option>
                            <option value="vc">Saint Vincent &amp; Grenadines</option>
                            <option value="st">Sao Tome and Principe</option>
                            <option value="sa">Saudi Arabia</option>
                            <option value="sn">Senegal</option>
                            <option value="rs">Serbia</option>
                            <option value="sc">Seychelles</option>
                            <option value="sl">Sierra Leone</option>
                            <option value="sg">Singapore</option>
                            <option value="sk">Slovakia</option>
                            <option value="si">Slovenia</option>
                            <option value="sb">Solomon Islands</option>
                            <option value="za">South Africa</option>
                            <option value="kr">South Korea</option>
                            <option value="es">Spain</option>
                            <option value="lk">Sri Lanka</option>
                            <option value="sr">Suriname</option>
                            <option value="sz">Swaziland</option>
                            <option value="se">Sweden</option>
                            <option value="ch">Switzerland</option>
                            <option value="tw">Taiwan</option>
                            <option value="tj">Tajikistan</option>
                            <option value="tz">Tanzania</option>
                            <option value="th">Thailand</option>
                            <option value="tg">Togo</option>
                            <option value="tt">Trinidad and Tobago</option>
                            <option value="tn">Tunisia</option>
                            <option value="tr">Turkey</option>
                            <option value="tm">Turkmenistan</option>
                            <option value="tc">Turks and Caicos Islands</option>
                            <option value="vi">US Virgin Islands (USA)</option>
                            <option value="ug">Uganda</option>
                            <option value="ua">Ukraine</option>
                            <option value="ae">United Arab Emirates</option>
                            <option value="gb">United Kingdom</option>
                            <option value="us" selected>United States</option>
                            <option value="uy">Uruguay</option>
                            <option value="uz">Uzbekistan</option>
                            <option value="ve">Venezuela</option>
                            <option value="vn">Vietnam</option>
                            <option value="ye">Yemen</option>
                            <option value="zm">Zambia</option>
                            <option value="zw">Zimbabwe</option>
        </select>

    <div class="float-right">
      <label for="drop2">Location:</label>
      <select name="drop2" id="dropForm">
                          <option value="AL" type="text" >Alabama</option>
                          <option value="AK" type="text" >Alaska</option>
                          <option value="AZ" type="text" >Arizona</option>
                          <option value="AR" type="text" >Arkansas</option>
                          <option value="CA" type="text" >California</option>
                          <option value="CO" type="text" >Colorado</option>
                          <option value="CT" type="text" >Connecticut</option>
                          <option value="DE" type="text" >Delaware</option>
                          <option value="FL" type="text" >Florida</option>
                          <option value="GA" type="text" >Georgia</option>
                          <option value="HI" type="text" >Hawaii</option>
                          <option value="ID" type="text" >Idaho</option>
                          <option value="IL" type="text" >Illinois</option>
                          <option value="IN" type="text" >Indiana</option>
                          <option value="IA" type="text" >Iowa</option>
                          <option value="KS" type="text" >Kansas</option>
                          <option value="KY" type="text" >Kentucky</option>
                          <option value="LA" type="text" >Louisiana</option>
                          <option value="ME" type="text" >Maine</option>
                          <option value="MD" type="text" >Maryland</option>
                          <option value="MA" type="text" >Massachusetts</option>
                          <option value="MI" type="text" >Michigan</option>
                          <option value="MN" type="text" >Minnesota</option>
                          <option value="MS" type="text" >Mississippi</option>
                          <option value="MO" type="text" >Missouri</option>
                          <option value="MT" type="text" >Montana</option>
                          <option value="NE" type="text" >Nebraska</option>
                          <option value="NV" type="text" >Nevada</option>
                          <option value="NH" type="text" >New Hampshire</option>
                          <option value="NJ" type="text" >New Jersey</option>
                          <option value="NM" type="text" >New Mexico</option>
                          <option value="NY" type="text" >New York</option>
                          <option value="NC" type="text" >North Carolina</option>
                          <option value="ND" type="text" >North Dakota</option>
                          <option value="OH" type="text" >Ohio</option>
                          <option value="OK" type="text" >Oklahoma</option>
                          <option value="OR" type="text" >Oregon</option>
                          <option value="PA" type="text" >Pennsylvania</option>
                          <option value="RI" type="text" >Rhode Island</option>
                          <option value="SC" type="text" >South Carolina</option>
                          <option value="SD" type="text" >South Dakota</option>
                          <option value="TN" type="text" >Tennessee</option>
                          <option value="TX" type="text" >Texas</option>
                          <option value="UT" type="text" >Utah</option>
                          <option value="VT" type="text" >Vermont</option>
                          <option value="VA" type="text" >Virginia</option>
                          <option value="WA" type="text" >Washington</option>
                          <option value="WV" type="text" >West Virginia</option>
                          <option value="WI" type="text" >Wisconsin</option>
                          <option value="WY" type="text" >Wyoming</option>
                      </select>
    </div>

    <br />
    <br />

    <label for="zip">Zip Code:</label>
    <input type="text" name="zip" size="12" />

    <div class="float-right">
      <label for="phoneNumber">Phone No:</label>
      <input type="text" name="phoneNumber" required/>
    </div>

    <br />
  </div>

  <br />

  <div class="center-element">
    Gender:
    <label for="gender">Male:</label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" />
    <label for="gender">Female:</label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" />
  </div>

  <br />

  <hr />


  <div class="center-element">
    <b>Any additional info:</b>
    <br />
    <br />


    <label for="sub">Subject:</label>
    <input type="text" name="sub" id="sub" placeholder="topic" />
    <!--SUBJECT BAR-->


    <br />
    <br />

    <textarea type="text" placeholder="Ask us a question..." id="notePad" rows="8" cols="50"></textarea>

    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
  </div>

  <hr />




  <button type="reset" id="reset-button">Clear form</button>
  <!--reset button-->

  <br />
  <br />


  <button type="submit" id="submit-form-button">Get Started</button>
  <!--submit button-->


</form>
```

Comment: well i have not taught myself bootstrap as yet. So is it not possible to have it aligned with only CSS? This is my first form btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the input alignment give the labels on the left a `width` and set their display to `inline-block`.

```
.label-left {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 8em;
}
```

To align the subject, I would position the label subject absolutely...

```
.center-element {
  position: relative;
}

.subject {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45px;
  left: 80px;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 100%;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2.3em;
  /*1em = 16px.*/
}


/*OVERALL FORM EDITING*/

form {
  margin: auto;
  /*used to center the form*/
  width: 700px;
  /*prevents the form from stretching over the whole page*/
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding: 20px;
  /*pads the inside of the form*/
  font-size: 0.875em;
  /*1em = 16px.*/
}


/*OVERALL FORM EDITING*/

.center-element {
  text-align: center;
}

.float-right {
  float: right;
}


/*position input fields to the right on the form*/


/*INPUT FIELDS*/

input[type="text"] {
  /*controls the size, color, e.t.c for the input "text" fields */
  border-radius: 7px;
  border: 2px solid #f4511e;
  padding: 6px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 190px;
}

input[type="text"]:focus {
  /*for the color inside the input "text" fields when clicked*/
  background-color: #9BDFE4;
}

input[type="number"] {
  /*controls the size, color, e.t.c for the input "number" fields */
  display: inline-block;
  /*allows our elements to have a width and a height.*/
  border-radius: 7px;
  border: 2px solid #F28C6D;
  padding: 6px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
  width: 190px;
  /*used to specify the size of the input fields*/
}

input[type="number"]:focus {
  /*for the color inside the input "number" fields when clicked*/
  background-color: #9BDFE4;
}


/*INPUT FIELDS*/


/*BUTTONS*/

#submit-form-button {
  /*for the "Get Started" button*/
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 12px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #F28C6D;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}

#submit-form-button:hover {
  /*controls the color of the "Get Started" button when you hover over it*/
  background-color: #EB4408;
}

#reset-button {
  /*for the "Clear form" button*/
  border-radius: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #9BDFE4;
  float: right;
  outline: none;
}

#reset-button:hover {
  /*controls the color of the "Clear form" button when you hover over it*/
  background-color: #0066CC;
}


/*BUTTONS*/


/*DROPDOWN MENUS*/

#dropForm {
  display: inline-block;
  /*allows our elements to have a width and a height.*/
  border-radius: 7px;
  border: 2px solid #f4511e;
  padding: 6px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
  width: 190px;
  /*used to specify the size of the input fields*/
}


/*DROPDOWN MENUS*/


/*TEXT AREA BOX & SUBJECT AREA BOX*/

#sub {
  width: 395px;
  padding: 12px;
}

#notePad {
  border-radius: 7px;
  border: 2px solid #f4511e;
  padding: 12px;
  outline: none;
  resize: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#notePad:focus {
  background-color: #9BDFE4;
}

.center-element {
  position: relative;
}

.label-left {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 8em;
}

.subject {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45px;
  left: 95px;
}
```

```html
<form>


  <div id="aligning-input-fields">
    <label for="firstname" class="label-left">First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" required/>

    <div class="float-right">
      <label for="lastname">Last Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="lastname" required/>
    </div>

    <br />
    <br />

    <label for="email-1" class="label-left">Enter your e-mail:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email-1" required/>

    <div class="float-right">
      <label for="email-2">Confirm your email:</label>
      <input type="text" name="email-2" required/>
    </div>

    <br />
    <br />

    <label for="drop1" class="label-left">Country:</label>
    <select name="drop1" id="dropForm">
                            <option value="au">Australia</option>
                            <option value="al">Albania</option>
                            <option value="dz">Algeria</option>
                            <option value="ao">Angola</option>
                            <option value="ai">Anguilla</option>
                            <option value="ag">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
                            <option value="ar">Argentina</option>
                            <option value="am">Armenia</option>
                            <option value="aw">Aruba</option>
                            <option value="at">Austria</option>
                            <option value="az">Azerbaijan</option>
                            <option value="bs">Bahamas</option>
                            <option value="bh">Bahrain</option>
                            <option value="bd">Bangladesh</option>
                            <option value="bb">Barbados</option>
                            <option value="by">Belarus</option>
                            <option value="be">Belgium</option>
                            <option value="bz">Belize</option>
                            <option value="bj">Benin</option>
                            <option value="bm">Bermuda</option>
                            <option value="bt">Bhutan</option>
                            <option value="bo">Bolivia</option>
                            <option value="ba">Bosnia and Herzegovina</option>
                            <option value="bw">Botswana</option>
                            <option value="br">Brazil</option>
                            <option value="vg">British Virgin Islands</option>
                            <option value="bn">Brunei</option>
                            <option value="bg">Bulgaria</option>
                            <option value="bf">Burkina Faso</option>
                            <option value="ca">Canada</option>
                            <option value="kh">Cambodia</option>
                            <option value="cm">Cameroon</option>
                            <option value="cv">Cape Verde</option>
                            <option value="ky">Cayman Islands</option>
                            <option value="td">Chad</option>
                            <option value="cl">Chile</option>
                            <option value="cn">China</option>
                            <option value="co">Colombia</option>
                            <option value="cr">Costa Rica</option>
                            <option value="hr">Croatia</option>
                            <option value="cy">Cyprus</option>
                            <option value="cz">Czech Republic</option>
                            <option value="ci">Côte d&#39;Ivoire</option>
                            <option value="dk">Denmark</option>
                            <option value="dm">Dominica</option>
                            <option value="do">Dominican Republic</option>
                            <option value="ec">Ecuador</option>
                            <option value="eg">Egypt</option>
                            <option value="sv">El Salvador</option>
                            <option value="ee">Estonia</option>
                            <option value="fj">Fiji</option>
                            <option value="fi">Finland</option>
                            <option value="fr">France</option>
                            <option value="ga">Gabon</option>
                            <option value="gm">Gambia</option>
                            <option value="de">Germany</option>
                            <option value="gh">Ghana</option>
                            <option value="gr">Greece</option>
                            <option value="gd">Grenada</option>
                            <option value="gu">Guam (USA)</option>
                            <option value="gt">Guatemala</option>
                            <option value="gw">Guinea-Bissau</option>
                            <option value="gy">Guyana</option>
                            <option value="ht">Haiti</option>
                            <option value="hn">Honduras</option>
                            <option value="hk">Hong Kong</option>
                            <option value="hu">Hungary</option>
                            <option value="is">Iceland</option>
                            <option value="in">India</option>
                            <option value="id">Indonesia</option>
                            <option value="ie">Ireland</option>
                            <option value="il">Israel</option>
                            <option value="it">Italy</option>
                            <option value="jm">Jamaica</option>
                            <option value="jp">日本</option>
                            <option value="jo">Jordan</option>
                            <option value="kz">Kazakhstan</option>
                            <option value="ke">Kenya</option>
                            <option value="kw">Kuwait</option>
                            <option value="kg">Kyrgyzstan</option>
                            <option value="la">Laos</option>
                            <option value="lv">Latvia</option>
                            <option value="lb">Lebanon</option>
                            <option value="lr">Liberia</option>
                            <option value="li">Liechtenstein</option>
                            <option value="lt">Lithuania</option>
                            <option value="lu">Luxembourg</option>
                            <option value="mo">Macau</option>
                            <option value="mk">Macedonia</option>
                            <option value="mg">Madagascar</option>
                            <option value="mw">Malawi</option>
                            <option value="my">Malaysia</option>
                            <option value="ml">Mali</option>
                            <option value="mt">Malta</option>
                            <option value="mr">Mauritania</option>
                            <option value="mu">Mauritius</option>
                            <option value="mx">Mexico</option>
                            <option value="fm">Micronesia</option>
                            <option value="md">Moldova (Republic of)</option>
                            <option value="mn">Mongolia</option>
                            <option value="ms">Montserrat</option>
                            <option value="ma">Morocco</option>
                            <option value="mz">Mozambique</option>
                            <option value="mm">Myanmar</option>
                            <option value="na">Namibia</option>
                            <option value="np">Nepal</option>
                            <option value="nl">Netherlands</option>
                            <option value="nz">New Zealand</option>
                            <option value="ni">Nicaragua</option>
                            <option value="ne">Niger</option>
                            <option value="ng">Nigeria</option>
                            <option value="mp">Northern Mariana Islands (USA)</option>
                            <option value="no">Norway</option>
                            <option value="om">Oman</option>
                            <option value="pk">Pakistan</option>
                            <option value="pw">Palau</option>
                            <option value="pa">Panama</option>
                            <option value="pg">Papua New Guinea</option>
                            <option value="py">Paraguay</option>
                            <option value="pe">Peru</option>
                            <option value="ph">Philippines</option>
                            <option value="pl">Poland</option>
                            <option value="pt">Portugal</option>
                            <option value="pr">Puerto Rico (USA)</option>
                            <option value="qa">Qatar</option>
                            <option value="cg">Republic Of Congo</option>
                            <option value="ro">Romania</option>
                            <option value="ru">Russia</option>
                            <option value="rw">Rwanda</option>
                            <option value="kn">Saint Kitts &amp; Nevis Anguilla</option>
                            <option value="lc">Saint Lucia</option>
                            <option value="vc">Saint Vincent &amp; Grenadines</option>
                            <option value="st">Sao Tome and Principe</option>
                            <option value="sa">Saudi Arabia</option>
                            <option value="sn">Senegal</option>
                            <option value="rs">Serbia</option>
                            <option value="sc">Seychelles</option>
                            <option value="sl">Sierra Leone</option>
                            <option value="sg">Singapore</option>
                            <option value="sk">Slovakia</option>
                            <option value="si">Slovenia</option>
                            <option value="sb">Solomon Islands</option>
                            <option value="za">South Africa</option>
                            <option value="kr">South Korea</option>
                            <option value="es">Spain</option>
                            <option value="lk">Sri Lanka</option>
                            <option value="sr">Suriname</option>
                            <option value="sz">Swaziland</option>
                            <option value="se">Sweden</option>
                            <option value="ch">Switzerland</option>
                            <option value="tw">Taiwan</option>
                            <option value="tj">Tajikistan</option>
                            <option value="tz">Tanzania</option>
                            <option value="th">Thailand</option>
                            <option value="tg">Togo</option>
                            <option value="tt">Trinidad and Tobago</option>
                            <option value="tn">Tunisia</option>
                            <option value="tr">Turkey</option>
                            <option value="tm">Turkmenistan</option>
                            <option value="tc">Turks and Caicos Islands</option>
                            <option value="vi">US Virgin Islands (USA)</option>
                            <option value="ug">Uganda</option>
                            <option value="ua">Ukraine</option>
                            <option value="ae">United Arab Emirates</option>
                            <option value="gb">United Kingdom</option>
                            <option value="us" selected>United States</option>
                            <option value="uy">Uruguay</option>
                            <option value="uz">Uzbekistan</option>
                            <option value="ve">Venezuela</option>
                            <option value="vn">Vietnam</option>
                            <option value="ye">Yemen</option>
                            <option value="zm">Zambia</option>
                            <option value="zw">Zimbabwe</option>
        </select>

    <div class="float-right">
      <label for="drop2">Location:</label>
      <select name="drop2" id="dropForm">
                          <option value="AL" type="text" >Alabama</option>
                          <option value="AK" type="text" >Alaska</option>
                          <option value="AZ" type="text" >Arizona</option>
                          <option value="AR" type="text" >Arkansas</option>
                          <option value="CA" type="text" >California</option>
                          <option value="CO" type="text" >Colorado</option>
                          <option value="CT" type="text" >Connecticut</option>
                          <option value="DE" type="text" >Delaware</option>
                          <option value="FL" type="text" >Florida</option>
                          <option value="GA" type="text" >Georgia</option>
                          <option value="HI" type="text" >Hawaii</option>
                          <option value="ID" type="text" >Idaho</option>
                          <option value="IL" type="text" >Illinois</option>
                          <option value="IN" type="text" >Indiana</option>
                          <option value="IA" type="text" >Iowa</option>
                          <option value="KS" type="text" >Kansas</option>
                          <option value="KY" type="text" >Kentucky</option>
                          <option value="LA" type="text" >Louisiana</option>
                          <option value="ME" type="text" >Maine</option>
                          <option value="MD" type="text" >Maryland</option>
                          <option value="MA" type="text" >Massachusetts</option>
                          <option value="MI" type="text" >Michigan</option>
                          <option value="MN" type="text" >Minnesota</option>
                          <option value="MS" type="text" >Mississippi</option>
                          <option value="MO" type="text" >Missouri</option>
                          <option value="MT" type="text" >Montana</option>
                          <option value="NE" type="text" >Nebraska</option>
                          <option value="NV" type="text" >Nevada</option>
                          <option value="NH" type="text" >New Hampshire</option>
                          <option value="NJ" type="text" >New Jersey</option>
                          <option value="NM" type="text" >New Mexico</option>
                          <option value="NY" type="text" >New York</option>
                          <option value="NC" type="text" >North Carolina</option>
                          <option value="ND" type="text" >North Dakota</option>
                          <option value="OH" type="text" >Ohio</option>
                          <option value="OK" type="text" >Oklahoma</option>
                          <option value="OR" type="text" >Oregon</option>
                          <option value="PA" type="text" >Pennsylvania</option>
                          <option value="RI" type="text" >Rhode Island</option>
                          <option value="SC" type="text" >South Carolina</option>
                          <option value="SD" type="text" >South Dakota</option>
                          <option value="TN" type="text" >Tennessee</option>
                          <option value="TX" type="text" >Texas</option>
                          <option value="UT" type="text" >Utah</option>
                          <option value="VT" type="text" >Vermont</option>
                          <option value="VA" type="text" >Virginia</option>
                          <option value="WA" type="text" >Washington</option>
                          <option value="WV" type="text" >West Virginia</option>
                          <option value="WI" type="text" >Wisconsin</option>
                          <option value="WY" type="text" >Wyoming</option>
                      </select>
    </div>

    <br />
    <br />

    <label for="zip" class="label-left">Zip Code:</label>
    <input type="text" name="zip" size="12" />

    <div class="float-right">
      <label for="phoneNumber">Phone No:</label>
      <input type="text" name="phoneNumber" required/>
    </div>

    <br />
  </div>

  <br />

  <div class="center-element">
    Gender:
    <label for="gender">Male:</label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" />
    <label for="gender">Female:</label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" />
  </div>

  <br />

  <hr />


  <div class="center-element">
    <b>Any additional info:</b>
    <br />
    <br />


    <label for="sub" class="subject">Subject:</label>
    <input type="text" name="sub" id="sub" placeholder="topic" />
    <!--SUBJECT BAR-->


    <br />
    <br />

    <textarea type="text" placeholder="Ask us a question..." id="notePad" rows="8" cols="50"></textarea>

    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
  </div>

  <hr />


  <button type="reset" id="reset-button">Clear form</button>
  <!--reset button-->

  <br />
  <br />


  <button type="submit" id="submit-form-button">Get Started</button>
  <!--submit button-->


</form>
```

[Codepen if you prefer](http://codepen.io/sol_b/pen/bqLjYw)

Comment: oh ok, so that is where I went wrong, thank again ovokuro.

Comment: so I just finish editing it, and now I saw what you did what you did here, so you turned the labels into block elements so that we are able to control the space/width around them, which worked perfectly. And for the subject input field, I would have never figured that out. thank you. Now i know how useful making labels into block elements can be.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using bootstrap for the whole page.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">

  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <form style="width:100%">
      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-2">

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-8" style="text-align:center !important">
          <p>First Name:</p>
          <p> <input type="text" name="firstname" required/></p>

          <p>First Name:</p>
          <p> <input type="text" name="firstname" required/></p>

          <p>First Name:</p>
          <p> <input type="text" name="firstname" required/></p>


          <p>First Name:</p>
          <p> <input type="text" name="firstname" required/></p>


        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2">

        </div>

      </div>

    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">

  </div>
</div>
```

**Do not forget to reference the bootsrap**

```
<head><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"</head>
```

Comment: this does not help me, I don't know bootstrap, is there anyone that can assist me with this?